# split array from csv into columns

Tags: python, sql, etl

i have this CSV Data

```
number,event_date,event_timestamp,event_name,event_params
0,20220315,1668314165054758,eventTracking,"[{'key': 'test0', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': 1665374225, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
 {'key': 'test1', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': 0, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
 {'key': 'test2', 'value': {'string_value': 'http:\test.com', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
 {'key': 'test3', 'value': {'string_value': 'A@gmail.com', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
 {'key': 'test4', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': 5, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}]"
```

i want to get this:

```
number,event_date,event_timestamp,event_name1,event_params1
0,20220315,1668314165054758,test0,None
0,20220315,1668314165054758,test1,None
0,20220315,1668314165054758,test2,http:\test.com
0,20220315,1668314165054758,test3,A@gmail.com
0,20220315,1668314165054758,test4,None
```

can you please help?
Thank you

Comment: This isnt a free code writting service. What have you tried, what errors have you faced?

Comment: How does this relate to SQL?

Comment: sorry Chris, i have also search and tested some python query which i found from the google but it doesn't work and because i am newbie with python therefore i ask here. Sure i will post the Error next time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import re
# >>> re.sub(r'([A-Z])(?!$)', r'\1,', 'ABC')
df = pd.read_csv("check.csv")
print(df)
# It will take the list/dict from the relevant column
dc = df.event_params.iloc[0]
print(dc)

# The list is actually a string so we need to you eval
# Before the eval we need to fix the dict by adding comma after }}
r = re.sub("}}", r"}},", dc)
ev = eval(r)

# To get the number and event_date I just taking the column value
number = df.number.iloc[0]
event_date = df.event_date.iloc[0]

# Now lets loop over the dict and get the needed values
event_timestamp = []
event_name1 = []
event_params1 = []

for i in ev:
    print(i['value'])
    print(i.keys())
    event_timestamp.append(i['value']['int_value'])
    event_name1.append(i['key'])
    event_params1.append(i['value']['string_value'])


# Now creating final dataFrame and inserting all the values
df_final = pd.DataFrame()

df_final['event_timestamp'] = event_timestamp
df_final['event_name1'] = event_name1
df_final['event_params1'] = event_params1
df_final['number'] = 0
df_final['event_date'] = 20220315
df_final = df_final[['number', 'event_date', 'event_timestamp', 'event_name1', 
'event_params1']]

print(df_final)

# Save as csv
df_final.to_csv("This_is_what_you_nees.csv")
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ivan Lisi, Thank you very much. i would like to ask you, when i try to run the code on the  check.csv which has about 100 rows, the only first 9 rows were processed. Therefore i think the problem is on this loop "for i in ev:" . i changed it to for "i in 1000:" to make i  run 1000 loop, but it show an Error "in correct syntax" . Do you know why?

Comment: You can't make for loop 1000. It has no meaning.
It is hard to day why your data with 1000 rows don't work without checking what is going on.